# JSON format in R refuse to parse?

Tags: r, json, dataframe

Here is my toy JSON:

```
"[[143828095,86.82525,78.50037,0.011764707,1.0,1,1],  
[143828107,86.82525,78.50037,0.015686275,1.0,1,0], 
[143828174,84.82802,83.49646,0.015686275,1.0,1,0], 
[143828190,83.3301,92.4895,0.011764707,1.0,1,0], 
[143828206,83.3301,92.4895,0.011764707,1.0,1,-1], 
[143828251,119.482666,98.4848,0.03137255,1.0,2,1], 
[143828325,123.30899,95.93237,0.027450982,1.0,2,0], 
[143828334,128.47015,92.4895,0.027450982,1.0,2,0], 
[143828351,128.47015,92.4895,0.027450982,1.0,2,-1], 
[143828406,115.19141,60.514465,0.019607844,1.0,3,1], 
[143828529,121.183105,61.51367,0.019607844,1.0,3,0], 
[143828551,121.183105,61.51367,0.019607844,1.0,3,-1], 
[143828696,105.502075,94.26935,0.023529414,1.0,8,1], 
[143828773,105.502075,94.26935,0.023529414,1.0,8,-1],
[143829030,78.24274,58.18811,0.023529414,1.0,DEL,1], 
[143829107,78.24274,58.18811,0.023529414,1.0,DEL,-1], 
[143831178,127.47159,76.28339,0.023529414,1.0,8,1],
[143831244,127.47159,76.28339,0.023529414,1.0,8,-1]]"
```

Now I want to parse it (`fromJSON()`) but

> DEL

within the JSON prevents me to do this.

Please advise how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute "DEL" for, say, 0.

```
json_string <- "[[143828095,86.82525,78.50037,0.011764707,1.0,1,1], [143828107,86.82525,78.50037,0.015686275,1.0,1,0], [143828174,84.82802,83.49646,0.015686275,1.0,1,0], [143828190,83.3301,92.4895,0.011764707,1.0,1,0], [143828206,83.3301,92.4895,0.011764707,1.0,1,-1], [143828251,119.482666,98.4848,0.03137255,1.0,2,1], [143828325,123.30899,95.93237,0.027450982,1.0,2,0], [143828334,128.47015,92.4895,0.027450982,1.0,2,0], [143828351,128.47015,92.4895,0.027450982,1.0,2,-1], [143828406,115.19141,60.514465,0.019607844,1.0,3,1], [143828529,121.183105,61.51367,0.019607844,1.0,3,0], [143828551,121.183105,61.51367,0.019607844,1.0,3,-1], [143828696,105.502075,94.26935,0.023529414,1.0,8,1], [143828773,105.502075,94.26935,0.023529414,1.0,8,-1], [143829030,78.24274,58.18811,0.023529414,1.0,DEL,1], [143829107,78.24274,58.18811,0.023529414,1.0,DEL,-1], [143831178,127.47159,76.28339,0.023529414,1.0,8,1], [143831244,127.47159,76.28339,0.023529414,1.0,8,-1]]"
json_string <- gsub("DEL", 0, json_string) # You can make the zero any number you like
fromJSON(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

using a json parser (http://json.parser.online.fr/), just deleting the "DEL" at the respective places seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I need the DEL, I want to make this column as character and sometimes user deletes the digit, I need to record it.

Comment: Okay, what about replacing the "DEL" string with some unique numeric value? Tried this again in the parser and it worked fine. `json <- stringr::str_replace_all(json,"DEL", 9999)` in r